# Execute time on HTML by Python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a website by Python, but when I executed this line:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import socket

from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
host_name = {'HostName' : socket.gethostname()}
cmd = "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
ip_address, err =  p.communicate()
ip_address = {"IP" : ip_address[:-1]}

@app.route("/")
def info():
    dateNow = {'Date' : str(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))}
    timeNow = {'Time' : str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))}
    return '''
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Galileo Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
       <h1 align = "center"> Welcome to VGU </h1>
       <p align = "center"> 
           Host Name: ''' + host_name['HostName'] + '''<br> 
           IP Address: ''' + ip_address['IP'] + '''<br>
           Date: ''' + dateNow['Date'] + '''<br>
           Current time:'''+timeNow['Time']+'''<br>
</p> 
</body>
</html>
'''
```

The website showed an error that

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str.

Can you help me to fix this? Thank you 
P/s: All variables are defined.

Comment: It is not enough information, Can you post Minimal Working part of your code?

Comment: Do you want me to type out the code here?

Comment: Add your code to question.

Comment: Can you please re-check

Answer (score 0):

The `p.communicate()` returns an encoded string so you need to decode it.
Also `time.strftime` would return string so no need to convert it to a string.

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import socket

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from datetime import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)
host_name = {'HostName': socket.gethostname()}
cmd = "ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'"
p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
ip_address, err = p.communicate()
ip_address, err = ip_address.decode(), err.decode()
ip_address = {"IP": ip_address[:-1]}


@app.route("/")
def info():
    dateNow = {'Date': time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}
    timeNow = {'Time': time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}
    return '''
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Galileo Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
       <h1 align = "center"> Welcome to VGU </h1>
       <p align = "center"> 
           Host Name: ''' + host_name['HostName'] + '''<br> 
           IP Address: ''' + ip_address['IP'] + '''<br>
           Date: ''' + dateNow['Date'] + '''<br>
           Current time:'''+timeNow['Time']+'''<br>
</p> 
</body>
</html>
'''


app.run()
```

Comment: So you mean this: p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).decode() and: timeNow = {'Time': str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))} ??

Comment: No look at my code the `p.communicate()` will return a byte string (encoded string) and you need to decode it (with `.decode()`).
`time.strftime` returns a normal string so there is no need to use `str()` function.